Circle detection on a mask - cheaper alternative
I have segmented masks of a few circles. They are segmented from kirby bauer test image using U-net segmentation model.
I want to get the coordinates of circle centers and their corresponding radii with some computationally cheap algorithms.
Original image sample: link to image
Mask sample: link to image
Example of identified circles: link to image
Circles can also overlap: link to image
I tried Hough Circle transform from scikit-image (because strangely I was not able to get opencv's variables into simple x,y,r variable in python). Anyways Hough feels like an overkill for this task. On top of it, it is misidentifiying some circles or missing. Would appreciate suggestions for alternative algorithms.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import time
from skimage.transform import hough_circle, hough_circle_peaks
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter

start = time.time()

# Load picture and detect edges
filename = '/home/muhammad-ali/Downloads/test2.jpg'
image = cv.imread(filename, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
# image.shape
image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
image = cv.resize(image, (1024, 1024), interpolation = cv.INTER_LINEAR)
edges = canny(image, sigma=3, low_threshold=10, high_threshold=50)

# Detect two radii
hough_radii = np.arange(40, 1000, 20)
hough_res = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)

# Select the most prominent 3 circles
accums, cx, cy, radii = hough_circle_peaks(hough_res, hough_radii, total_num_peaks=20)

# Draw them
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(10, 4))
draw = np.zeros([1024,1024,3])
for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
    circy, circx = circle_perimeter(center_y, center_x, radius, shape=draw.shape)
    draw[circy, circx] = (220, 20, 20)

# ax.imshow(draw, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
# plt.figure(figsize = (250,250))
plt.axis('off')
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(draw, 'gray')
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(image, 'gray')

end = time.time()
length = end - start
print("It took", length, "seconds!")

output
It took 2.9625961780548096 seconds!

As you can see it is an overkill with too many mistakes. I need an alternative that is cheaper because the model will be used in low-resource environments.

You definitely don’t need UNET for something like this. And no Hough either. I would start with better illumination, which would make the problem trivial.

I also agree that UNET is a complicated solution for this task. Have you ever tried using blob detector of OpenCV?

bad picture. the light source is reflecting on the surface of the dish's contents. you need to fix that. before the picture is taken.
